python calling executable with popen;, file written by executable can not be accessed
I have a C++ file
#include <cstdio>

int main(int iArgC, char *apArgV[]) {
    int iResult = -1;
    if (iArgC > 1) {
        FILE *fOut = fopen(apArgV[1], "wt");
        if (fOut != NULL) {
            fprintf(fOut, "hello\n");
            fprintf(fOut, "goodbye\n");
            fclose(fOut);
            printf("Written `%s`\n", apArgV[1]);
            iResult = 0;
        } else {
            printf("Coudn´t open %s\n", apArgV[1]);
        }
    } else {
        printf("I need an argument\n");
    }
    return 0; 
}

which i compile like this
g++ -g -o hello hello.cpp

When i run ./hello /home/jody/hihi,txt the file hihi.txt is written.
Then i have this python script
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess as sp
import time

def callHello(file_name) :
    command = ["/home/jody/progs/polyhedronLED/version_c/hello", file_name]
    proc = sp.Popen(command,
                    stdout=sp.PIPE,
                    stderr=sp.PIPE)
    sOut, sError = proc.communicate()
    iResult = proc.returncode
    print("return code: %d"%iResult)
    print("Output:      %s"%sOut)
# -- end def

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_name0 = "/home/jody/hihi.txt"
    callHello(file_name0)
    
    ff = open(file_name0, "wt")
    lines = ff.readlines()
    ff.close()
    print("output\n%s"%lines)
# -- end if

When i run this script, i get the output:
return code: 0
Output:      b'Written `/home/jody/hihi.txt`\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jody/progs/polyhedronLED/version_c/./hellocall.py", line 22, in <module>
    lines = ff.readlines()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

But when i subsequently check the output directory, the file hihi.txt has been written.
I also tried it with a delay time.sleep(5) after  the call to callHello() but the result was the same.
I then wrote a bash script which calls hello and subsequently reads the contents of the file: this worked as expected.
When (or how) can a file written by a subprocess be actually accessed in python?

You open the file in write-only mode.

As mentioned in the comments, you opened the file in write-only mode. Change line 21 from ff = open(file_name0, "wt") to ff = open(file_name0, 'rt') or just ff = open(file_name0). If you need to both read and write the file, you can pass 'wt+' as the second argument to open it in read-write mode.
